# Get Gmail mails via SMTP "Send Mail as" in IMAP "Sent" Folder?

Tags: gmail

I use Gmail with many different Email Accounts like name@mydomain.com - therefore I forward all emails to my Gmail Account and in Gmail I use the "Send Mail as" option, to include my name@mydomain.com and send Emails in the name of that (or others).

Of course I therefore do not use Gmail Server, I use "send through mydomain.com's SMTP Servers" so that nobody will see the difference.

In the past, if I use an IMAP Tool like Outlook, Emails send with Outlook for name@mydomain.com get also on my server in the "Sent" Folder (same as Inbox syncronisation).

IS there any way, that the emails send via Gmail will also be "duplicated" on my servers "IMAP" folders?

Reason: if I ever switch away from Gmail, I not only want all my received emails save in my servers inbox, I also want duplicates of my sent mails.

Comment: To make it a bit more clear: I use Gmail the "normal private way" with https://mail.google.com (not Google Business Apps) and send mails online - under Settings, Accounts and Import I use "Send mail as" and implemented my email name@mydomain.com, Mail is sent through: smtp.mydomain.com - now I want that sent emails also occur in the "Sent" folder of my IMAP Server of mydomain.com.

Comment: In that case, Gmail does not have the kind of functionality that you are as asking for, AFAIK.  It only knows to connect to your domain's SMTP server, it does not know to also connect to your server's IMAP server to store the sent email.

Answer (score 1):

IMAP is only for managing emails on the server.  It cannot be used for sending emails.  That must be done with SMTP.  SMTP has no concept of IMAP, and most (if any) SMTP servers do not automatically copy a sent email into an IMAP "Sent" folder.  So when programmably sending an email via SMTP, you usually have to log in to the associated IMAP account and manually copy the sent email into the "Sent" folder yourself.  IMAP tools like Outlook do exactly that.  And there is an IMAP extension ([RFC 6154](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6154)) that many IMAP servers implement ([Gmail does](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#special-use_extension_of_the_list_command)) for identifying the "Sent" folder regardless of how it is actually named.

Comment: Thx for the clarification, now I got IMAP and SMTP more - so Outlook logs in into my name@mydomain.com IMAP Account and copys the mail into  the "Sent" Folder.
But is also possible that Gmail does this, when I use https://mail.google.com to send a mail which is sent through: smtp.mydomain.com with the Gmail Setting "Send mail as"?

Answer (score -1):

If you don't use smtp.gmail.com to send your messages, and want them in your Gmail inbox anyway, you'll obviously have to put them yourself.

- Either you put the message with [IMAP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview), in the sent folder
- Either you put the message with the [Google API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert), and apply label `SENT`.

Comment: The question is about sending via GMail web client in the name of other accounts, not the other way round.